# what's the definition of object in python?

Tags: python, oop, object

> Everything is object in Python!

I was wondering, what the hell definition of **object** in Python ? I can't find a clear answer. any idea?

i have found some opinions:

1.objects can be assigned to a variable or passed as an argument to a function .

2.objects must have attributes and methods.

3.objects are subclassable.

Comment: do you have any prior knowledge of OOPS ?

Comment: objects are not subclassable, classes are. Objects are instances of classes.

Comment: In python:  function, class,  str, int are all object so i was confused and wondering the definition of object in Python.

Answer (score 1):

An "Object is simply a collection of data (variables) and methods (functions) that act on those data."  To learn more I recommend you spend some time reading [Python Objects and Class](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class) and work though all the code samples.

From the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html):

Classes

Classes provide a means of bundling data and functionality together. Creating a new class creates a new type of object, allowing new instances of that type to be made. Each class instance can have attributes attached to it for maintaining its state. Class instances can also have methods (defined by its class) for modifying its state.

Compared with other programming languages, Python’s class mechanism adds classes with a minimum of new syntax and semantics. It is a mixture of the class mechanisms found in C++ and Modula-3. Python classes provide all the standard features of Object Oriented Programming: the class inheritance mechanism allows multiple base classes, a derived class can override any methods of its base class or classes, and a method can call the method of a base class with the same name. Objects can contain arbitrary amounts and kinds of data. As is true for modules, classes partake of the dynamic nature of Python: they are created at runtime, and can be modified further after creation

Comment: well, that's the general definition for object in oop language, In python `class` is object too, how can you explain that?

Comment: @ccw It means that, like in Java, Classes are represented by objects, that also have methods and data (for example, you can ask a class for its name). By "everything is an object" it is meant that there is nothing special, in the language, about classes, functions, integers, strings. There are no primitive values that are no objects (unlike in Java) and you can pass around functions (a little like in C++ but unlike Java). Modules are objects, too. I once wrote code that manipulated the imports in a module. Objects in python are, more or less, just dictionaries containing other objects.